# How do I make the player name show up on a /tellraw command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I am currently making a minecraft custom map *(for 1.9)*. I want to make the player *"say"* something using **/tellraw** commands. *I did figure out how to make the player name come up using **/say** commands*, but still have no idea how to do it using the **/tellraw** command.

How do I do that?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: I can try that...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to display a player name in /tellraw command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170483/is-there-a-way-to-display-a-player-name-in-tellraw-command)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use **[selectors](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_variables)**. These are things like `@a`, `@p`, etc. (Look at the link for adding things like scoreboard). To use this in `/tellraw`, use the following:

```
"extra":[{"selector":"@p"}]
```

So, let's say we want a command to say "Hi! My name is ..." Try this:

```
/tellraw @a {"text":"Hi! My name is ","extra":[{"selector":"@p"}]}
```

To break it down,

```
/tellraw @a                    @a means all, so this goes to everyone in the world

{"text":"Hi! My name is ",     The "text" part tells tellraw that the next part 
                               (denoted by :) in quotes is text to be displayed.

"extra":[{"selector":"@p"}]}   The "extra" tag says the next part is something 
                               extra (figures). Then, the "selector" tag says the 
                               next part is a selector, and "@p" means the nearest 
                               player from where the command is being run.
```

**Probably More than You Need to Known, Just Putting it Here Anyways**

To tell everyone in the world, use `@a`. To tell everyone with a score of 3 in the objective `Kills`, use

```
@a[score_Kills=3,score_Kills_min=3]
```

In English, it means "Anybody (`@a`) with a maximum score of `3` and a minimum score of `3`". This may sound weird, but since the only number with a maximum of 3 and a minimum of 3 is, well, 3, that command only targets players with 3 as their `Kills` score.