# Player variable in JSON

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a minigame where you have different kits. You step on a pressure plate and get all your armor and effects added. That's all working fine. I'm trying to make it so it places a sign above the pressure plate saying
"TAKEN"
"BY"
"[PLAYERWHOHASTHATKIT]"
In bold dark red
Is this possible? I've tried `/blockdata ~ ~-1 ~ {"Text3":"@p"}`with all the other text I want. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make the player name show up on a /tellraw command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/260323/how-do-i-make-the-player-name-show-up-on-a-tellraw-command)

Comment: I hate it when I flag several questions as duplicates of one, only to discover that my originally chosen canonical question is itself a duplicate.

Comment: @pppery I hate it when I VTC for a duplicate only to find out that duplicate is a duplicate itself  - I'm right on your trail :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the `selector` tag of the text component to resolve a selector into a name. It replaces `text`, `translate`, and `score` tags at that depth (such that you cannot use `selector` and `text` at the same time).

Example:

```
/blockdata ~ ~-1 ~ {"Text3":"{\"selector\":\"@p\",\"color\":\"dark_red\"}"}
```