# How to use @p in tellraw?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Me and my friends are making a game in minecraft and are using tellraw. How do we use @p in tellraw because we cannot find it anywhere! Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [Player variable in signs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269824/player-variable-in-signs)

Answer (score 2):

Add an object to the JSON that uses `"selector":"@p"` instead of the  `"text"` value. For example:

```
/tellraw @p ["Hello", {"selector":"@p","color":"red"}, {"text":"!","color":"red"}]
```

**I recommend using [this tellraw generator](http://commandfox.js.org/tellraw.html)**