# Make it look like the player who activated a command block said something they didn't say

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to do something with command blocks like:

```
/tellraw @a {"text":"[Name of person who activated the command block] Hello!"}
```

Without the person saying it themselves in the chat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make the player name show up on a /tellraw command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/260323/how-do-i-make-the-player-name-show-up-on-a-tellraw-command)

Comment: Or, at least, that's what I think it's asking; the question is kind of unclear.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to use /tellraw you can use `execute as @p[distance=..6,limit=1] run say hello` in a command block and the closest player (probably the one that pushed the button) will appear to say hello. If you use a button for activation you could then do some more things with player's rotation and position (depending on what side of what block the button is on) to make it so the closest player has to be the one that clicked the button because of where the button is.