# Help with the /tellraw command in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Recently I've wanted to get into command blocks. Using the tell raw command I want to copy the nearest player's name and then say something after the name.

```
/tellraw @a [{"selector":"@p"}]
```

That's what I have right now and I want to add some text behind it. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to display a player name in /tellraw command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170483/is-there-a-way-to-display-a-player-name-in-tellraw-command)

Answer (score 1):

Add a text component to the list:

```
/tellraw @a [{"selector":"@p"},{"text":", hello!"}]
```

Or just a string, which Minecraft allows for text:

```
/tellraw @a [{"selector":"@p"},", hello!"]
```

Comment: @MrShmardock if you found the answer helpful, click the check mark. It will help people with the same problem find it faster

Answer (score -1):

For 1.14+ I use

```
/tellraw @a {"text":"Hello!", "color":"green"}
```

I'm pretty sure that this works with 1.13.