# How do i get this tellraw command to say player name in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I display the player's name in this line? I tried different

```
/tellraw @p [{"text":"Hugh: ","color":"colorName"},{"text":"You did it!","color":"colorName"}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to display a player name in /tellraw command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170483/is-there-a-way-to-display-a-player-name-in-tellraw-command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
/tellraw @p [{"text":"Hugh: ","color":"colorName"},{"selector":"@p"},{"text":" You did it!","color":"colorName"}]
```