# Is there a way to /tellraw the output of a command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to `/tellraw` everyone the result of `/team list teamA`, which by itself would list the team members on teamA.

is there a way I can broadcast that to all players with a command block?

```
execute as @a at @s run team list blue
```

doesn't work, it only says the result in the command block's previous output bar

Using `/say` or `/tellraw` instead of `/execute` doesn't help either

There also isn't any NBT data with a player's team, or I am just unable to find it

I am fine if any type of command works as long as it says the `/team list` output in chat.

Comment: Do you mean you tried variants of `/say` and `/tellraw` to no avail, or do you mean that you don't want to use `/say` or `/tellraw` at all?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 no success, sorry I probably should have been more clear on that

Comment: Pro tips, when putting code inline, you only need to surround it with one backtick, not three. And when you put an entire command on its own line, the best way is to indent it by 4 spaces before the line, while leaving a blank line before and after. See my edits to your post.

Comment: Also, you've said that you've tried variants of `/say` and `/tellraw`. It's best that you put all your trials in your post, so that we don't suggest something you've already tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to display a player name in /tellraw command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170483/is-there-a-way-to-display-a-player-name-in-tellraw-command)

Comment: @pppery I suggest not marking this a duplicate.The (answers to) the other question give a start towards a solution, it doesn't solve the problem by itself; there's a bit missing. Specifically: I don't see how to put an arbitrary command in the extra.selector param of /tellraw, or what a selector-equivalent of /team list is. For example, there's no instruction on how to escape things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you yet tried this command?

```
/tellraw @a {"selector":"@a[team=teamA]"}
```

This command will list all the players on team `teamA`.