# How do I put a player's name in a /title command? in JE 1.12.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I put a player's name in a /title command? in JE 1.12.2
I tried

```
title @a  title [{"text":"welcome","selector":"@p"}]
```

It printed only `welcome`. I tried this too:

```
title @a title [{"text":"@p welcome"}]
```

It printed `@p welcome`

I want '[player's name] welcome' as the title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to display a player name in /tellraw command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170483/is-there-a-way-to-display-a-player-name-in-tellraw-command)