# How do I inform a player another player passed by a certain place?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

If a player (I will call them P1) is on a pressure plate, I want the `/tellraw` command to tell them if a certain player (I will call them P2) just passed a prescribed place.

I know how to send the message directly to P1, but I do not know how to make the commands tell him that the one who passed the described place was P2 and not P3. I could use the `/say` to let P2 himself say that he is passing by there, but then P3 could read it too; what should I do? I am reposting because I missed some informations in the first post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to display a player name in /tellraw command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170483/is-there-a-way-to-display-a-player-name-in-tellraw-command)

Comment: [Gamepedia Tellraw Component Entry](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Raw_JSON_text_format#Java_Edition)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **/execute** command.

There are a lot of videos on YouTube.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Just telling someone to check out videos on YouTube is extremely unhelpful, and not what this site is for.

Comment: I told him about the command to look for. I did not just tell him to look for it on YT. I told him the name of the command, so that it would be easier for him too find.